# Move picturebox with keyboard

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am fairly new to c# and I want to make a picture box move when I press the WASD keys, but the picture box refuses to move.  The picture box is not docked, locked or anchored. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Imagebox_test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
            int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) x += 1;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) x -= 1;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) x -= 1;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) x += 1;

            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what's going on! thanks for the help!

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Put the caret at the beginning of `Form1_KeyDown` and press `F9` to insert a breakpoint. When the execution reaches the breakpoint, it will enter debug mode and you can step through the code and see what's going on. The first thing to look for is whether the breakpoint is ever reached - that is if the event is even fired.

Comment: Make sure KeyPreview is set to _true_ on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. Set the form's `KeyPreview` property to `true` otherwise it the `PictureBox` will get the `KeyDown` event. This was preventing `Form1_KeyDown` from being called.
2. This code block has a subtle bug:

   ```
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) x += 1;
   else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) x -= 1;
   else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) x -= 1;
   else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) x += 1;
   ```

   If you look closely, you're only modifying the x coordinate.

All together:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set these 2 properties in the designer, not here.
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
    int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) x += 1;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) x -= 1;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) y -= 1;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) y += 1;

    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the form's KyePreview property to true otherwise form will not take that key down event.
Secondly you are only changing x value and not y value.
The whole completed code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Imagebox_test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
KeyPreview = true; 
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
            int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) x += 1;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) x -= 1;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) y -= 1;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) y += 1;

            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```